# Finish long directory name with tab problem

Tags: directory

I have simple problem that I have to long directories which I want to cd into, but I would like to know easy way.

```
mosquito@mosquito-K56CB:~/Downloads$ ls | grep Guns
Guns n' Roses - Appetite for Destruction (Japanese Edition) 1987
Guns n' Roses - Use Your Illusion I 1991
```

Of course I can just copy the name and put it like this: `cd "Guns n' Roses - Appetite for Destruction (Japanese Edition) 1987"`

But why when I write `cd Guns` then tab, it finishes line into: `cd Guns\ n\'\ Roses\ -\` then by my understanding I should just start writing App.. with tab and it should finish whole name, but it does not. And hitting tab twice does not show me anything either. What I am missing here?

Comment: I never knew the trick with the tab key - thanks!  You might look into being able to open a terminal in a directory from nautilus - this link shows how to enable that function.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu

Comment: @user1880405 I've tested it. It seems character `'` has some objections try after removing it.

Comment: You are right sir, removing ' fixed the problem, now I will know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Actually trying the same directory names in `bash`, I get the same error. Removing the `'` from the directory names makes it work, so I'm guessing that this is a bug in the `bash` tab-completion.

**EDIT 2**: According to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/415043/strange-autocompletion-behavior), it's a known bug that will be fixed in a future release.

You could still try `zsh` as a drop-in replacement and install the Grml zsh config, which really takes you to a whole new level of tab completion:

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
wget -O ~/.zshrc http://git.grml.org/f/grml-etc-core/etc/zsh/zshrc
wget -O ~/.zshrc.local  http://git.grml.org/f/grml-etc-core/etc/skel/.zshrc
zsh
```

If you like it and want to use it as your default shell, run `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh`.

Comment: Hitting tab 3 or any amount of times does not do anything. Added your line, didn't change anything.

Comment: Please see my edit, I think bash-completion is just buggy.

Comment: I see now, thanks kraxor. But those 2 methods (copying name and 'tabbing') are the only ways to get into multiple word directory?

Comment: You could do something like `cd Gun<TAB>*Japan*` as a workaround. But if you use the terminal quite often, you should definitely try `zsh`, once you get there, you never even look back. It's pretty much compatible so you don't have to learn anything new, just enjoy the extra features.

Comment: Wow that's a nice trick! Anyways, gonna take a look into zsh as you say. Thank you, case solved.